# Fluent ui react theme for teams

Tags: themes, microsoft-teams, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am am building a teams app, I want to set the teams theme using fluent theme, what are the exact values for theme in theme provider,
Can i use fluentui/Northstar and fluentui/react together?

Comment: Refer: https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.56.0/quick-start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at [Designing your Microsoft Teams app with UI templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/design/design-teams-app-ui-templates?tabs=desktop#getting-started-with-tools-and-samples). The templates are a collection of Fluent UI-based components that work across common Teams use cases, giving you more time to figure out the best experience for your users.

Comment: I am currently using fluent/react detailslist, I have wrapped it in teamstheme provider from fluent/Northstar. When I change the teams theme the theme is not getting applied to the details list components from. Fluent react, when all the other components from fluent Northstar are working fine

Comment: How to handle teams theme ( default, dark, contrast) modes for  fluent react based components

Answer (score 0):

You can use package '@fluentui/react-northstar' for handling teams theme.

Use it something like below:
import { Provider, teamsTheme, teamsDarkTheme, teamsHighContrastTheme } from '@fluentui/react-northstar'

```
public setThemeComponent = () => {
    const rtl = i18n.dir() === "rtl";

    if (this.state.theme === "dark") {
        return (
            <Provider theme={teamsDarkTheme} rtl={rtl}>
                <div className="darkContainer">
                    {this.getAppDom()}
                </div>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
    else if (this.state.theme === "contrast") {
        return (
            <Provider theme={teamsHighContrastTheme} rtl={rtl}>
                <div className="highContrastContainer">
                    {this.getAppDom()}
                </div>
            </Provider>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <Provider theme={teamsTheme} rtl={rtl}>
                <div className="defaultContainer">
                    {this.getAppDom()}
                </div>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Also you can refer below sample apps for it:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-company-communicator/blob/master/Source/CompanyCommunicator/ClientApp/src/App.tsx